# Export data from the Google Sheet to PDF PYTHON

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am getting all the data present in google sheet using code below,
i want to write all these data to the pdf file and download that.

```
import gspread
import sys 
print(sys.path)
import os
#sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages')
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
path = os.path.abspath('cred.json')
credentials=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('cred.json',scope)
client=gspread.authorize(credentials)
sheet=client.open('xyz').sheet1
data=sheet.get_all_records()
print(data)
```

Comment: Okay? Soooo.... What's the question? Did you face an issue with your current code? What's the problem that's occuring?

Comment: You want to download the 1st tab of Google Spreadsheet of `xyz` as a PDF file. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: my code is running,,yes i want to download all the data of xyz sheet in pdf,@Tanaike.Can you tell me how can i do this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I suggested an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to export Google Spreadsheet of `xyz` as a PDF file using gspread with python and the service acccount.

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, the Spreadsheet cannot be directly export as a PDF file using gspread. So in this case, `requests` library and the endpoint for exporting Spreadsheet to PDF are used.

When the points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
import gspread
import sys 
print(sys.path)
import os
#sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages')
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
path = os.path.abspath('cred.json')
creds=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('cred.json',scope)
client=gspread.authorize(creds)

# I added below script
spreadsheet_name = 'xyz'
spreadsheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name)
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?format=pdf&id=' + spreadsheet.id
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + creds.create_delegated("").get_access_token().access_token}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open(spreadsheet_name + ".pdf", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you hav ealready been able to get values from Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful this.
- If an error related to Drive API, please enable Drive API at the API console.
- If an error related to the service account, please modify `create_delegated("")` to `create_delegated("email of the service account")`.

Comment: About `Is creds supposed to be credentials?`, oh, it's yes. `creds.create_delegated("").get_access_token().access_token` of `creds` is `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('cred.json',scope)`. So, I modified it. Thank you for your comment.